# DateTime.ParseExact throws expcetion on windows xp

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, datetime, window

I have Following line of code:

```
dt.Rows[0]["duedate"] = DateTime.ParseExact(textBox_duedate.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

where "duedate" is DateTime column in DataTable dt. When I run this on windows 7 having .Net framework 3.5, it runs fine but when I run this on windows xp SP3 having .Net framework 3.5 (it also has .Net framework 2.0 installed), my app throws an exception "String was not recognized as a valid datetime...."

When I see the "loaded assembly information" in exception details, It seems to load .net framework assembly version 2.0. Can this also be the problem? moreover How can I make my application to use .net assembly version 3.5? I am compiling my application in Visual studio 2010.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what is in textBox_duedate.Text?

Comment: did you set the target framework to 3.5?

Comment: You didn't post the text you're parsing.

Comment: @Adil textbox_duedate.Text has string date in the format e.g. 23-11-2012.

Comment: btw .net 3.5 is an in-place update for .net 2.0. The runtime version will still be 2.0. i.e. your application will always use 3.5 when it's installed.

Comment: @KuyaJohn Yup! I have .Net framework 3.5 selected in my project application properties.

Comment: You should try a minimal working example, without controls or `DataTable`s.

Comment: does it change something when you try "dd'-'MM'-'yyyy" for your pattern ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is not the issue of framework, because its an issue of the OS current culture. Both the pc has different culture settings in their OS that's why this problem is occurring.

Try this instead

```
dt.Rows[0]["duedate"] = DateTime.ParseExact(textBox_duedate.Text, 
                            new CultureInfo("en-US")).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: He's already specifying `InvariantCulture`, so the OS culture shouldn't affect his parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the input string contains spaces? You could `Trim` it before parsing it.